# Vuejs2 listen to page scroll fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Am using vuejs2 with codeigniter.

I have added the following to the html

```
<header id="test_header">
     my nav menu
</header>
```

In a separate  scripts.js i have

```
script.js

new Vue({
 el: '#test_header',
 data:function(){
  return{

  }
},
methods:{
    handleScroll(){
        console.log("on scroll");
    },
    listenScroll(){
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }
},
mounted() {
  this.listenScroll();
},
destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
});
```

Am trying to listen to the scroll event but the function is only executed once. That is console.log("on scroll") executes only during mount   but the function is never executed when the page scrolls

i have included the javascript files in the html in the following order

```
<html> 
  <body> 
   <script src="vuejs.js"> //includes vuejs frameworks
   <script src="script.js"> ///includes above code
  </body>
 </html>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: It might be notable that the `scroll` event by default doesn't *bubble*.

Comment: @connexo what do you mean that it doesnt bubble?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the event listener for the scroll event in `created()`

ex

```js
  created(){
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.myFunction);
  }
```

Also you methods object should look like:

```js
{
  myFunction: function(){},
  anotherFunction: function(){}
}
```

[Working js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tavmqsrp/4/)

Comment: Thanks it works but i had to add passive true like window.addEventListener("scroll", this.myFunction,true); to remove a warning "Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event"